# How can I center a continuous raster layer by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation using qgis raster calculator?

Tags: statistics, calculator, raster, qgis

I'm trying to extrapolate a spatial model to a map in QGIS using the raster calculator. The model predicts the value of a pixel given the environmental conditions at this location (e.g. elevation, slope, ect.). Hence, each explanatory variable is a raster layer. For the model I centered my covariates by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. Now I want to do the same to my raster layers. As trivial as this seems, I didn't manage to do so. I tried (among similar attempts - like changing upper case, etc.):

```
(my.raster-mean(my.raster))/sd(my.raster)
```

The calculator tells me the expression is valid, however, mean() and sd() don't work. And I could not find a site with the built-in functions for the raster calculator.
Any help in this is most apreciated! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: QGIS questions probably get more attention at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I posted the question on [link] (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148872/how-can-i-center-a-continuous-raster-layer-by-subtracting-the-mean-and-dividing)